Subquery of select * vs Subquery of select fields
Need help in understanding which of the following snowflake SQL is faster and why. provided tablea has 50 columns. Or do You think both are equally efficient.
select col1, col2 from (select * from tablea /*AdditionalLogc*/)
--Vs
select col1, col2 from (select col1, col2 from  tablea /*AdditionalLogc*/)


Any decent query optimizer should treat them the same.

but the compile time in Snowflake is a real thing. I prefer the second myself, as it is explicit, and as complexity arrives, to points to "where" the columns came from and help the thinking process of the humans

Your question as it currently stands doesn't make any sense, you can simply remove the subqueries. If you really need them, you should point out why and improve the question.

I prefer a CTE over a subquery.  And always choose columns over * in Snowflake.

Snowflake uses Columnar storage. So, selecting all columns from a table of 50 columns is going to be far more I/O intensive than selecting two columns.
So, based on the limited context you have provided, the 2nd option is better i.e.
select col1, col2 from (select col1, col2 from  tablea /AdditionalLogc/)
